# extracting multiple fields from a text file using php

Tags: php, regex

what is the best way of extracting multiple (~40 values) from a text file using php?

the data is more or less like:

```
NAMEA                   valuea
NAMEB                   valueb
```

I'm looking for a proper* approach to extracting this data into a data-structure, because i will need to specify regexs for all of them (all 40).

did i make myself clear?

*meaning, the default/painful method would be for me to do:

```
$namea = extractfunction("regexa", $textfilevalue);
$nameb = extractfunction("regeb", $textfilevalue);
```

... 40 times!

---

The lines may not be in the same order, or be present in each file. Every NAMEA is text like: "Registration Number:", or "Applicant Name:" (ie, with spaces in what i was calling as NAMEA)

---

Response to the Col.

i'm looking for a sensible "way" of writing my code, so its readable, modifiable, builds an object/array thats easily callable, etc... "good coding style!" :)

---

@Adam - They do actually... and contain slashes as well...

---

@Alix - Freaking marvelous man! THat was GOOD! would you also happen to have any insights on how I can "truncate" the rsultant array by removing everything from "key_x" and beyond? Should i open that as a new question?

Comment: what does it mean "i will need to specify regexs for all of them (all 40)"? you can't supply one regex for all values? but why? what's too complicated in them? isn't it just space separated values?

Comment: Without specifications or real example text, it's nigh impossible to answer your question.

Comment: Re: update on key format, you'll have to let us know a more well-defined data file format before we can show you workable code. Some solutions work if the file uses delimiters, some solutions work if the fields are fixed-length, etc.

Comment: With conditions you stated you have only one choice. Sooner you start to write, less time it take.

Comment: Also I voted to close this question because without the actual example of the real data it is just empty blab, not the real question.

Comment: @Dave: Check my answer, I've updated it. If something doesn't work please provide us with an excerpt of the data (3-5 lines should do it) so we can try to figure out the best way to handle this.

Comment: @Dave, please reply to individual answers as comments when appropriate, rather than appending to your question. This question is becoming very disjointed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my take at it:

**somefile.txt:**

```
NAMEA                   valuea
NAMEB                   valueb
```

**PHP Code:**

```
$file = file_get_contents('./somefile.txt');
$string = preg_replace('~^(.+?)\s+(.+?)$~m', '$1=$2', $file);
$string = str_replace(array("\r\n", "\r", "\n"), '&', $string);

$result = array();

parse_str($string, $result);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($result);
echo '</pre>';
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [NAMEA] => valuea
    [NAMEB] => valueb
)
```

You may also be able to further simplify this by using [`str_getcsv()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php) on PHP 5.3+.

---

**EDIT**: My previous version fails for keys that have spaces like @Col. Shrapnel noticed. I didn't read the question with enough attention. A possible solution since you seem to be using keys that always have `:` appended is this:

```
$string = preg_replace('~^(.+?):\s+(.+?)$~m', '$1=$2', $file);
```

To remove everything from `key_x` to the end of the file you can do something like this:

```
$string = substr($string, 0, strpos($string, 'key_x'));
```

So the whole thing would look like this:

**somefile.txt:**

```
Registration Number:                   valuea
Applicant Name:                   valueb
```

**PHP Code:**

```
$file = file_get_contents('./somefile.txt');
$string = substr($file, 0, strpos($file, 'key_x'));
$string = preg_replace('~^(.+?):\s+(.+?)$~m', '$1=$2', $string);
$string = str_replace(array("\r\n", "\r", "\n"), '&', $string);

$result = array();

parse_str($string, $result);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($result);
echo '</pre>';
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [Registration_Number] => valuea
    [Applicant_Name] => valueb
)
```

Comment: (ie, with spaces in what i was calling as NAMEA) - read the question carefully.

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel: Indeed, I haven't read the whole question at first. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks Alix - wonderfully answered! Addressed every single point, works wonderously!!

Answer (score 0):

as far as I get it you can use file() to get an array of strings and then parse these strings with some regexp.

if you add a = sign between names and values, you'll be ble to get the whole thing at once using [parse_ini_file()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your keys (namea, nameb) never have spaces in them:

```
$contents = file('some_file.txt'); // read file as array
$data = array();
foreach($contents as $line) { // iterate over file
    preg_match('/^([^\s]+)\s+(.*)/', $line, $matches); // pull out key and value into $matches

    $key = $matches[1];
    $value = $matches[2];

    $data[$key] = $value; // store key/value pairs in $data array
}

var_dump($data); // what did we get?
```